# Why do the semaphores lock even though they receive the post operation?

Tags: c, linux, posix, semaphore

I have the following code where I initialize the semaphores with sem_init function and set the pshared parameter to 1 so that the semaphores are shared between processes. After I run the code, only 60 and 40 are printed and the execution stops without terminating, however, semaphore X and Y are signalled. Why does the program stop?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t X;
sem_t Y;
sem_t Z;
int n;

int main() {
    sem_init(&X, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&Y, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&Z, 1, 0);

    n = fork();

    if (n == 0) {
        sem_post(&X);
        printf("%d\n", 40);
        sem_wait(&Y);
        printf("%d\n", 30);
        sem_wait(&Z);
        printf("%d\n", 45);
        exit(0);
    }
    sem_post(&Y);
    printf("%d\n", 60);
    sem_wait(&X);
    printf("%d\n", 10);
    printf("%d\n", 80);
    sem_post(&Z);

    return (0);
}
```

I expect the code to print 60 40 30 10 80 45, however, it only prints 60 and 40. Why does the parent stop at sem_wait(&X) although the child process executes sem_post(&X)?

Comment: You have not followed the manual instructions. [sem_init manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html): If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between
       processes, and **should be located in a region of shared memory**.

Comment: What changes should be for this code to behave like I expected?

Comment: As it says, place the semaphores in shared memory. The sem_init manual points you to to an example in the [shm_open manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) which has code showing how to do that.